# QML Event before and after property change

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Are there any signals I can bind to that allow me to execute functions directly before and directly after a property changes?

For example something like this:

```
Canvas {
    id: canvas
    anchors.fill: parent

    property real lastX
    property real lastY

    property var lastContext

    function cacheImage(){
        lastContext = canvas.context
    }

    function loadImageFromCache(){
        canvas.context = lastContext
        canvas.requestPaint()
    }
}
```

I want to call the `cacheImage()` function right before the canvas's size changes and the `loadImageFromCache()` right after the resize is completed.

If I understand correctly the `onWidthChanged` and `onHeightChanged` do the latter, but I need to save the image before it does that. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: See my comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442597/how-to-get-previous-property-value-before-it-changed-in-qml/48444844#48444844) question, maybe that could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But `cacheImage()` doesn't have to be called right before the size changes! It needs to be called any time after the most recent canvas contents change, and before the new canvas size takes effect. The window to cache the canvas is very long and extends between changes. The event "before n-th property change" is simply "after (n-1)-th property change" :)

Comment: I didn't even think of it that way, it works great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of functionality is not part of the "core design intent" of QML, so you are not getting it out of the box.

It is quite easy to do for C++ objects when you get to implement your own setter function.

But even in QML you can simply use an auxiliary setter function rather than using the property directly:

```
function setSomeProp(newValue) {
  if (newValue === oldValue) return
  stuffBeforeChange()
  oldValue = newValue
  stuffAfterChange() // optional, you can use the default provided signal too
}
```

If you insist on using a property based syntax, you can use an additional auxiliary property:

```
property type auxProp
onAuxPropChanged: setSomeProp(auxProp)
```

Which will allow you to use the `=` operator as well as do bindings.